# Homogeneous Transformation matrix from DH table

Tags: matrix

I am very new to mathematics and I'm trying to write a code for getting the link frame transformation equations (0T1, 1T2...) using for loop. I am having some success with a poorly written code however I am having "null" with my elements in my matrices.

Please help me out. Here is my code

```
 DH = {{0, T1, 0, 0}, {0, T2, L1, Pi/2}, {0, T3, L2, 0}, {0, 0, L3, 0}} (

For [i = 1, i <= 4, i++,
    A = {{Cos[DH[[i, 2]]], -Sin[DH[[i, 2]]], 0, DH[[i, 3]]},{Sin[DH[[i, 2]]] Cos[DH[[i, 4]]], Cos[DH[[i, 2]]] Cos[DH[[i, 4]]], -Sin[DH[[i, 4]]], -Sin[DH[[i, 4]]] DH[[i, 1]]}, {Sin[DH[[i, 2]]] Sin[DH[[i, 4]]], Cos[DH[[i, 2]]] Sin[DH[[i, 4]]], Cos[DH[[i, 4]]], Cos[DH[[i, 4]]] DH[[i, 1]]}, {0, 0, 0, 1}} 
    Print["A = ", MatrixForm[A]] ;]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're really close as it is, it just needs a `;` before the `Print[...]`.

```
DH = {{0, T1, 0, 0}, {0, T2, L1, Pi/2}, {0, T3, L2, 0}, {0, 0, L3, 0}} 
For[i = 1, i <= 4, i++, 
A = {
 {Cos[DH[[i, 2]]], -Sin[DH[[i, 2]]], 0, DH[[i, 3]]}, 
 {Sin[DH[[i, 2]]] Cos[DH[[i, 4]]], Cos[DH[[i, 2]]] Cos[DH[[i, 4]]], -Sin[
  DH[[i, 4]]], -Sin[DH[[i, 4]]] DH[[i, 1]]}, 
 {Sin[DH[[i, 2]]] Sin[DH[[i, 4]]], Cos[DH[[i, 2]]] Sin[DH[[i, 4]]], Cos[DH[[i, 4]]], Cos[DH[[i, 4]]] DH[[i, 1]]}, 
 {0, 0, 0, 1}
}; 
Print["A = ", MatrixForm[A]];
]
```

[image: For loop with Print]

Though something a little more *Mathematica*-y is to replace the `For` loop with [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)

```
Column@Table[
 Row@{
  "A =", 
  MatrixForm@{
   {Cos[DH[[i, 2]]], -Sin[DH[[i, 2]]], 0, DH[[i, 3]]},
   {Sin[DH[[i, 2]]] Cos[DH[[i, 4]]], Cos[DH[[i, 2]]] Cos[DH[[i, 4]]], -Sin[DH[[i, 4]]], -Sin[DH[[i, 4]]] DH[[i, 1]]},
   {Sin[DH[[i, 2]]] Sin[DH[[i, 4]]], Cos[DH[[i, 2]]] Sin[DH[[i, 4]]], Cos[DH[[i, 4]]], Cos[DH[[i, 4]]] DH[[i, 1]]},
   {0, 0, 0, 1}
  }
 },
{i, 4}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, do you have any suggestions to define the A matrix? Like using a loop of something. I tried doing a nested loop but I was not able to get results